# How to get ons-icon to load the icon dynamically?

Tags: angular, onsen-ui2

I've been having an issue with using the ons-icon and angular2 for a while.

```
<span *ngFor="let theIcon of item.getItem().style.get('icon')">
   <ons-icon [icon]="theIcon"></ons-icon> {{theIcon}}
</span>
```

While {{theIcon}} does display the proper icon text (md-cutlery), ons-icon never shows the icon.  If I copy the text into the control and change it to icon="md-cutlery", it displays fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular2 you have different directives to create bindings, you have directives for [Attribute, Class, and Style Bindings](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings). Since you want to create an attribute binding you need to do:`[attr.icon]="myIconVar"`

So your code should be:

```
<span *ngFor="let theIcon of item.getItem().style.get('icon')">
   <ons-icon [attr.icon]="theIcon"></ons-icon> {{theIcon}}
</span>
```