# Dynamically changing a button icon

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Given the following button,

```
  <button
      icon = 'ui-icon-check'
      type = 'text'
      pButton
      label = 'Age'
      iconPos = 'right'></button>
```

I would like to dynamically change the icon assigned to the button icon property:

My attempt is as shown below:

### ng.html

```
  <button
      [icon] = 'btnIcon'
      type = 'text'
      pButton
      label = 'Age'
      iconPos = 'right'></button>
```

### ng.component

```
....
btnIcon: string = 'ui-icon-check'
```

The icon is correctly assigned when the component initializes.

However, when I do

### ng.cmponent

```
if(this.form.valid)
{this.btnIcon = 'ui-icon-information'}
```

although the form is valid, the icon does not change as expected.

Any idea is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ons-icon to load the icon dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054548/how-to-get-ons-icon-to-load-the-icon-dynamically)

Comment: As you can see on the other question you need to use `[attr.icon] = 'btnIcon'`

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment noted give this a try

```
 <button
      [attr.icon] = 'btnIcon'
      type = 'text'
      pButton
      label = 'Age'
      iconPos = 'right'></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a function:

Define your function to select the icon:

**ng.component**

```js
selectIcon() {
  return this.form.valid ? 'ui-icon-check' : 'ui-icon-information';
}
```

Call the function in the property `icon`

**ng.html**

```html
<button
      [icon] = 'selectIcon()'
      type = 'text'
      pButton
      label = 'Age'
      iconPos = 'right'></button>
```